# Are questions about data recovery on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question is inspired by [Retrieving text documents from a 2.0Mb/2.0 HD floppy disk?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5135/278), which has attracted close-votes for being off-topic.

Do we consider questions about data recovery on-topic?

Other, previous examples include:

- [How can I copy files from a Compaq Deskpro?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4792/278)

Answer (score 4):

If you are recovering data from a retrocomputer or an old medium then yes, this is on-topic.

Similarly, I would suggest that converting files stored in formats that are no longer supported, in order to recover the data is also on-topic.

We already have several such [questions](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/617/276) that have been well received.

Of course, all such questions would come under the same rules of what constitutes "retro".